# codeigniter database error number 1064 on update data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to update user data in the Code-igniter (user details)
below is my code for more checking . please check it out why I get error when i push "update" button.
*note: I used some of these information in my view that I didn't copied theme for now (no need in-fact )*
controller:

```
public function edit(){
    //validation form
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[16]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|min_length[3]|max_length[50]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2','Confirm Password','trim|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cellphone','Cellphone Number','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('activation_code','Activation Code','trim');

    //$data['groups'] = $this->User_model->get_groups();
    //$data['user'] = $this->User_model->get_user($uid);

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //view

        $data = array(
            'userid'            =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->id,
            'first_name'        =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->first_name,
            'last_name'         =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->last_name,
            'fathers_name'      =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->fathers_name,
            'id_card_number'    =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->id_card_number,
            'national_number'   =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->national_code,
            'national_code'     =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->national_code,
            'age'               =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->age,
            'gender'            =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->gender,
            'is_addict'         =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->is_addict,
            'hiv_status'        =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->hiv_status,
            'hepatitis_status'  =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->hepatitis_status,
            'email'             =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->email,
            'needed_services'   =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->needed_services,
            'username'          =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')->username,
        );

        //$data['last_name'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id')->last_name;
        //$data['data'] = $this->Profile_Model->get_user_profile();
        //$this->base->set_message($msg,$type);
        redirect(site_url('admin/profile'),'refresh');
        $data['courses'] = $this->Profile_Model->get_user_profile();
        //load view
        $data['main_content'] = 'profile/index';


        $this->load->view('profile/layouts/main', $data);
    }else{
        //create articles data array

        $data = array(
            'first_name'        => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name'         => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'username'          => $this->input->post('username'),
            'email'             => $this->input->post('email'),
            'cellphone'         => $this->input->post('cellphone'),
            'group_id'          => 2,
        );
        if($this->input->post('user_id') == $this->session->userdata('user_id')->id){
            $uid = $this->input->post('user_id');
        }
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $password2 = $this->input->post('password2');
        if($password != '' && $password = $password2 ){
            $data['password'] = md5($this->input->post('password'));
        }
        if($this->input->post('activation_code') !=''){
            $data['activation_code'] = $this->input->post('activation_code');
        }
        $this->Profile_Model->update($data, $uid);

        //Create Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('User_saved','You have successfully registered');

        //redirect to page
        redirect('admin/profile');
    }
}
```

also below is my model snippet code:
model:

```
public function update($data, $uid)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $uid);
    $result = $this->db->update($this->table_users, $data);
    return $result;
}
```

and below is my view form:
view:

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('admin/profile/edit'),'class="form-horizontal"');?>
        <?php $uid = $this->session->userdata('user_id')->id;
        $uid = intval($uid);
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="first_name">نام</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $uid;?>">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name',$first_name);?>">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="last_name">نام خانوادگی</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('last_name',$last_name);?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="email">ایمیل</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php /** @var dbObject $email */
                echo set_value('email',$email);?>">  
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="username">نام کاربری</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username;?>" disabled aria-disabled="true" title="You cant't change your username" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="password">رمز ورود</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="password2">تایید رمز</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="cellphone">شماره تلفن همراه</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="tel" id="cellphone" name="cellphone" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="cellphone_activation">کد تایید پیامکی</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" id="cellphone_activation" name="cellphone_activation" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                <p>
                    <button class="btn mybtn btn-custom" type="submit">ویرایش</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Please show us the **complete** error message, and prefereably a PHP line number where it occured

Comment: problem is in your query try this   public function update($data, $uid)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $uid);
    $result = $this->db->update($this->table_users, $data);
     echo last_query(); exit;
}    copy paste the query in db and know the error .

Comment: so sorry to paste error message here
when I echo validation error I get this error:
`Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name.

The field was not set`

Comment: MD5 is considered broken for security purposes and is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: `if($password != '' && $password = $password2 ){` The right half of this conditional should use `==`. As written, it will save the password even if they don't match.

Answer (score 1):

Model Should be like this write table name instead of `$this->table_users`

```
public function update($data, $uid)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $uid);
    $result = $this->db->update(user, $data);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: but I have set table_users in the constructor before, I can access to load data from it. and maybe I want to change table names in feature.